# Transparent action bar set by fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an application which consists of a single activity consisting of a content frame for fragments with a navigation drawer which controls which fragment is displayed.

I'm trying to work out if I can make the action bar transparent for some of the fragments but not for others, looking at

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

and other questions on this site they all seem to give examples of creating different styles for the actionbar and setting these styles on a per activity basis in the manifest, is there a way to do this on a per fragment basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getActivity()` method in fragment to get activity context and get the actionbar instance. Then you can do whatever you wish to do with it.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar(); 
// replace getActivity() with ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()) if using appcompat
```

And then you can set transparent background to id:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#80000000")));
```

Comment: its not working for me,when i am using `ActionBar` with `ToolBar`

Comment: how to make it normal again?